# How to import my jQuery mobile themes with ThemeRoller to my website?

Tags: jquery, mobile, themes, themeroller

I have a small problem. Yesterday I created a new jQuery theme with the ThemeRoller. After that I've downloaded a zip file. Then it tells me to add some code into my website like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />`

I thought ok. After that I unzipped my zip-file, created a new css folder in my rootfolder and imported theme folder. So I've added this code to my site:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/test.css" />`

But oh wonder.. nothing happened. Where is my fault?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

To use your theme, add it to the head of your page after the jquery.mobile.structure file, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>jQuery Mobile page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/MY-CUSTOM-THEME-HERE.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0rc2.min.css" /> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script> 

</head>
```

http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/